# unexpected behavior of array passed as an argument instead of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Can you please explain to me why this code is printing the string 'John' instead of `['John']` or at least `[object]`

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log('hello ' + name);
}

greet('John');
greet(['Doe']);
```

Result:

```
hello John
hello Doe
```

And what is the difference between these two cases:

```
greet(['Doe']); // prints 'Doe'
console.log(['Doe']); prints "['Doe']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the `Array` to `String` at `+` operator. You can pass multiple parameters to `console.log()` using comma `,` operator between parameters.

```js
function greet(name) {
  console.log('hello ', name);
}

greet('John');
greet(['Doe']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is used in the expression `'hello' + name`, and the `+` operator coerces the array reference to a string. That's done via the `.join()` method internally, so joining all the component strings of the array `['Doe']` gives the string `"Doe"`.

You can type `['Doe'].toString()` in the browser console to check the string value.

Now, what `console.log()` does is another thing entirely. There's no real "spec" for it. It's a debugging tool, so the implementation tries to provide helpful output. Thus it does *not* simply call `.toString()` on an array argument, and instead gives a useful indication of what the value looks like.

Answer (score 0):

What Pointy said. In addition,

```
greet(['Mary', 'Doe']);
```

will output:

```
Mary,Doe
```